# Laravel Seed db:seed [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Fatal error: Class 'model' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy usando la herramienta FactoryModel para poblar la base de datos, para esto realicé lo siguiente:

creé el modelo:  `Php artisan make:model “Users” –m`

hice la migración: `php artisan migrate`

Modelo Users

```
{

 use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword; 

 protected $table = 'users'; 

 protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password','type']; 


 protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
 ];
}
```

en ModelFactory.php;

```
    $factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
        'password' => bcrypt('123'),
        'type' => 'administrador',
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

en dataseSeeder.php ;

```
public function run()
{
    model::unguard();

    factory('App\User','Administrador',3)->create();

    model::reguard();
}
```

poblar BD : php artisan db:seed

ERROR:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Fatal error: Class 'model' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Parece que en ModelFactory.php. usas App\User::class, pero tu modelo se llama Users, también no olvides configurar tu .evn.

Answer (score 1):

El error que muestra es debido a que usas 'model' en minúscula en el archivo DatabaseSeeder.php, la forma correcta según la documentación de Laravel, es en mayúscula, pues estás haciendo el llamado a la clase que referencias en `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        // ....

        Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

Comment: Exacto, tienes que usar la [facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/facades) para poder llamar a los métodos de la clase `Model`.